# Drop records based on column sub-string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Goal: drop records from Dataframe, based on column 2, `index 1`, sub-string.

I have tried:

```py
df = df[df[1] != '305-1']
df = df[df[1] != '305-2']
```

However, this is an absolute value, not a sub-string.

`df`:

```
    1   2   3
0   Emissions   305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Gro...   Emissions for Gross direct (Scope 1) GHG emiss...
1   Emissions   305-3~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Bio...   Emissions for Biogenic CO2 emissions was 14681...
2   Emissions   305-2~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~CO2 Emissions for CO2 was 107973 tons in year 2014...
3   Emissions   305-2~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~N20 Emissions for N20 was 91661 tons in year 2014,...
4   Emissions   305-3~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~HFCs    Emissions for HFCs was 31744 tons in year 2014...
```

Desired output `df`:

```
1   Emissions   305-3~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Bio...   Emissions for Biogenic CO2 emissions was 14681...
4   Emissions   305-3~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~HFCs    Emissions for HFCs was 31744 tons in year 2014...
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `|` for bitwise `or` with invert mask by `~`:

```
df[~df[1].str.contains('305-1|305-2')]
```

Or with specidied values in `[]`:

```
df[~df[1].str.contains('305-[12]')]
```

Comment: It works! Thank you @jezrael :) Will accept in 12 mins

Comment: Ty for the update; makes it a one-liner